# MessageBox inside paint event high CPU

Tags: .net, listview

I have a custom listview, and I wanted to debug something inside OnDrawSubItem function displayng a MessageBox. I expected some GUI freezing trying to repaint the item. The weird thing is that CPU goes 100% when I click the subitem (after the MessageBox). Can someone explain in what loop has fallen this?

```
class ListViewEx : ListView
{
    public ListViewEx()
    {
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
    }
    protected override void OnDrawColumnHeader(DrawListViewColumnHeaderEventArgs e)
    {
        e.DrawDefault = true;
    }
    protected override void OnDrawSubItem(DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("test");
        e.DrawDefault = true;
    }
}
```

EDIT

**If I do the same with paint event of a button I have not high CPU (just some repeated MessageBox)**

```
    private void btnTest_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("test");
    }
```

I know it's not right to display mbox inside paint events. I'm curious about the different behaviour in my two examples.

Answer (score 0):

Like [Alex's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965413/messagebox-inside-paint-event-high-cpu#comment26259341_17965413) suggests, you should never use message boxes as a debugging aid when you're working with UI code. They cause all kinds of problems and mask the behavior you're trying to debug.

A better solution involves either one or a combination of the following:

- breakpoints in strategic locations
- [Debug.Assert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.assert.aspx) to test assumptions
- [Debug.WriteLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine.aspx) to print diagnostics to the Output/Immedate Window

Comment: Out of interest: what are the problems it can cause? (Alex named one, and not very common one, I suppose)

Comment: @vines In addition to that, it changes lots of other behaviors. For example, if you're handling focus-related events, displaying and dismissing the message box changes the focus multiple times. Several controls do not like to have the focus jerked away from them in event handlers; TreeView is a good example.